# using shared_ptr of a type of Class A as a member variable of class B

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr

Assume that my class B is something like this:

```
class B {
B (double d,double e)
private:
std::shared_ptr < class A > sp;
}
```

The Constructor from class A looks like:

```
A(double a, double b){...};
```

Now, I want to write the constructor function for my class B, in which an object from class A is constructed(initialized or assigned) using the constructor function written above. Can someone explain me how can i do it professionally? I tried something like below but i get errors like "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument" and "an initializer list is unexpected in this context" ...

```
class B (double d, double e){
double a1 = d*2;
double b2=  e*2;
sp { std::make_shared<class A>(a1,b2) };
```

1. I'd appreciate to correct me either if i did typing mistake or if i misunderstood something conceptually(or any other explanation)
2. In general, why should we use make_shared? what are the other approaches and what are their pros and cons? Actually i don't understand if by `private: std::shared_ptr < class A > sp;` i already created the object by calling the default constructor of class A? So by make_shared i am creating another object?
3. How can i use the constructor initilizer list using : ?
   P.S According to one answer below, it seems that i cannot use the initializer list approach. Because the simple computation i wrote for a1 and b2 were only for showing my problem. My real computations are longer than that and I think i cannot use approaches like `B (double d,double e): sp{std::make_shared<A>(d*2, e*2)}` .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i use the constructor initilizer list using :

If you want to initialize `sp` you can do it in the **constructor initializer list**  as shown below, (and not inside the body of the constructor as you were doing):

```
//---------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-->constructor initializer list
B (double d,double e): sp{std::make_shared<A>(d*2, e*2)}
  {
      
  }
```

From [std::make_shared's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

> ```
> template< class T, class... Args > shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
> ```

`std::make_shared` is used to construct an object of type `T` and wraps it in a `std::shared_ptr` using `args` as the parameter list for the constructor of `T`.

(end quote)

---

The template parameter `T` in this case is `A` and thus `std::make_shared` is used to construct a `std::shared_ptr<A>` and initialize `sp` with it in the constructor initializer list.

Note that we can also use **in-class initializer** to initialize `sp`.

From [How to create and use `shared_ptr` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-shared-ptr-instances?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019):

> Whenever possible, use the `make_shared` function to create a `shared_ptr` when the memory resource is created for the first time. `make_shared` is **exception-safe**. It uses the same call to allocate the memory for the control block and the resource, which reduces the construction overhead. If you don't use `make_shared`, then you have to use an explicit `new` expression to create the object before you pass it to the `shared_ptr` constructor.

Comment: Thanks. But if i want to use the initializer list, where can i do the computations for my a1 and b2, which are going to be used for the construction later? You also wrote that i can use in-class initializer. I think it is what i was trying to do and i got the error.

Comment: @Denis I have updated the example in my answer. Check out my updated answer. In the updated answer, we are passing `d*2` and `e*2` to `A's` constructor which you wanted. Also, a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) might be more useful.

Comment: Actually the simple `e*2` computations i wrote in my question were only example, which made the confusion. My real computation are longer than that. And it seems i cannot do them in the initializer list approach. And using in_class approach gives me the error i wrote in my question...

Comment: @Denis In C++, initialization and assignment are different things. In your original example you were using `sp { std::make_shared<class A>(a1,b2) };` which isn't valid syntax. Also, we can only answer according to the given information in the question which in this case is `e*2` and `d*2`. We cannot guess what actual code you're using. You can extend the method given in my answer and if done correctly it should work. Also, you can ask a separate follow up question and make sure to post the real computation on that question so that people don't get misled.

Comment: You are right about the confusion, and sorry for that. 
But i think my question is not that much unclear. I want to use in-class approach, to do what one can do with `sp { std::make_shared<class A>(a1,b2) }`. And you are right, since i misunderstood the concepts of construction, initialization and assignement, i formulated my question very bad. But thanks for your hints

Comment: @Denis Then you can use `sp = std::make_shared<A>(d*2, e*2);` inside the constructor. Note that in the above statement i have removed the curly braces and added the `=` which means "assignment". And with this change the program will work. But again this is assignment. [Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/KzplbkZXI). In the above linked demo, i have a comment saying "do your calculation here".